# How to make table with fixed first column and vertical text to the left of fixed column

Tags: javascript, css

Made a table with first column fixed using this fiddle    link http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/6/    need a vertical text to left of fixed column(the text also vertical text also remains fixed like first column).

Difference between fiddle link and my expected output
1. the text 'co1' and 'co2' is vertically aligned
2. the vertical text should be fixed like the first column is.

fiddle code
1.HTML:

```
<div style="width:400px">

    <table class="table1">
        <tr>
            <thead>
                <th> make me fixed</th>
            </thead>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value number 1</td>     
       </tr>    
    </table>    

    <div class="table2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <thead>
                <th>make me scrollable eeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee</th>
            </thead>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> value number 2 </td>        
       </tr>    
    </table>    
    </div>

</div>
```

2.CSS

```
th,td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

.table1 {
    float: left;   
    }        
.table2 {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;  
    }
```

[Here's the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZugnY.jpg)

Comment: both were same.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand the question. Your output is the same in jsfiddle

Comment: @Moutimedia The text 'co1' and 'co2' is vertically aligned and is fixed like the first column. that's the diff. so my question is how can i implement those vertical text bar.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```css
th,td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

.table1 {
    float: left;   
    }        
.table2 {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;  
    }
    
.text-container {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 1rem;
}
    
.text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: .5rem;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="text">CO1</div>
  <div class="text">CO2</div>
</div>
<div style="width:400px">
    <table class="table1">
        <tr>
            <thead>
                <th> make me fixed</th>
            </thead>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value number 1</td>     
       </tr>    
    </table>    

    <div class="table2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <thead>
                <th>make me scrollable eeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee</th>
            </thead>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> value number 2 </td>        
       </tr>    
    </table>    
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i wanted the vertical text to span to multiple rows

Comment: Then just increase the fontsize and/or lineheight of the text class.